# Grep a word and from this position grep upwards for another word

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have a file like this:

```
Record 1
x1   5
x2       0  7  0'BCD
x31   18
x45      45
x67  4

Record 2
x1              9
x2      0  6  0'BCD
x3           8
x35            6
x45       7
x88     3

Record 3
x1              5
x2                 0  5  0'BCD
x4           18
x35            16
x98     3


Record 4
x1              5
x2                 0  4  0'BCD
x4           18
x35            16
x45      77
x98     3
```

For each record, I am interested of the values in front of x45 (if it exists in the record, if not exist then skip this record totally). And in case x45 is found, go up to get the value of x2

So the output desired will be (Note that Record3 doesn't have x45 so it is skipped:

```
   45 , 0  7  0'BCD
   7  , 0  6  0'BCD
   77 , 0  4  0'BCD
```

I can guarantee that if x45 exist then for sure x2 will exist
How can I do this with awk/sed/grep ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another `awk` solution:

```
awk -v search="x45" -v before="x2" '
  $1==before{ p=""; for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)p=((p=="") ? "" : p "  ") $i}
  $1==search{ print $2 " , " p }
' file
45 , 0  7  0'BCD
7 , 0  6  0'BCD
77 , 0  4  0'BCD
```

Or with some left-aligned formatting:

```
$ awk -v search="x45" -v before="x2" '
  $1==before{ p=""; for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)p=((p=="") ? "" : p "  ") $i}
  $1==search{ printf "%-3s, %s" ORS, $2, p }
' file
45 , 0  7  0'BCD
7  , 0  6  0'BCD
77 , 0  4  0'BCD
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F'\n' -v RS= '{print $NF, $2}' file

Address: street#3 Job:  Dentist
Address: street#4 Job:  Engineer
Address: street#5 Job:  Doctor
```

making the label input parameter

```
$ awk -F'\n' -v RS= -v term='Address' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                                          if($i~/^Job/) job=$i 
                                          else if($i~term) {a=$i; break}
                                        if(a) print a, job; 
                                        a=job=""}' file
```

it shouldn't print if the search term is not found but your example doesn't cover that case.  Note that as you specified if the search term is "Name" it won't work since "Job" appears after that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -nE '/^x2/h;/^x45/{H;x;s|x2(.*)\nx45(.*)|\2 ,\1|p}' file
      45       7
       7      41
      77                 133
```

You can pipe that to `column` to get a visually better output:

```
$ sed -nE '/^x2/h;/^x45/{H;x;s|x2(.*)\nx45(.*)|\2 ,\1|p}' file | column -t
45  ,  0  7  0'BCD
7   ,  0  6  0'BCD
77  ,  0  4  0'BCD
```